# Casting type streamreader to string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a list containing the following: name, initial, and age of a person, as in:

White, J, 23

Boucher, M, 30

Coetzee, G, 23

*I'm trying to do the following:*

Create a function that expects two parameters: parameter 1 is an integer called Age, parameter 2 is a string called fileName that takes in a filename on disk.

The function takes in the age from a textbox and filename statically typed into a second textbox (e.g. C:\nameList.txt)

**The function should scan/read the file specified, and make a count of all persons having the same age. I.e. if 23 was typed into the textbox, "2" will be displayed, since 2 people are 23 in the above example.**

*Now I'm trying to do this using the following logic:*

1. I'm using streamreader to read the text file and assign all words in
   the file as a single string to variable.
2. I will then split the string variable into many elements of an array
3. I will then loop over the textArray using an if-else statement to
   check if the index of the array matches the age to check for
   variable.
4. If match is found then increment counter variable to 1

In theory this is simple but I am having some problems with step 1. Here is my code for step 1:

```
        Function countAges(ByVal age As Integer, ByVal fileName As String) As Integer

        'Get Info From File'
        Dim textString As StreamReader
        textString = New StreamReader(fileName)
        textString.ReadToEnd()
        textString.Close()

        'index words to array'
        Dim allTextArray() As String
        allTextArray = textString.split 'HERE IS THE PROBLEM'
```

When trying to split the text which I got from the streamreader in textString variable I get the error *Split is not a member of system.IO*.

**Question:**

- Can you assign/cast streamreader text to a string variable? If so,
  how?
- Am I on the right track with this? Or is my logic flawed?

Please keep in mind I am new to VB when answering.

Comment: Calling a cat a dog doesn't make it bark.

Comment: *you can put a cat in the oven but that don't make it a biscuit*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the contents of the file and just throwing it away. The `ReadToEnd` method doesn't store the data from the file somewhere internally in the reader, it returns it as a string.

Put the string in a variable:

```
Dim textString As StreamReader
textString = New StreamReader(fileName)
Dim text as String = textString.ReadToEnd()
textString.Close()
```

Now you can use the string:

```
allTextArray = text.split
```

(Perhaps also renaming `textString` to something that better represents what it really is, as it's not a string but a `StreamReader`.)